# How can Doxygen HTML output be modified so it can be hosted with CSP sandbox header?

Tags: doxygen

I would like to host Doxygen HTML output from Nexus 3. This serves all content with the header

```
Content-Security-Policy "sandbox allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"
```

Doxygen fails to load with this header enabled (served directly with Nginx this time):

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.
    at readCookie (http://localhost:8080/resize.js:9:18)
    at HTMLDocument.initResizable (http://localhost:8080/resize.js:102:15)
    at e (http://localhost:8080/jquery.js:16:9980)
    at Object.fireWith (http://localhost:8080/jquery.js:16:10936)
    at Function.ready (http://localhost:8080/jquery.js:16:3982)
    at HTMLDocument.e (http://localhost:8080/jquery.js:16:9209)
```

I would rather not just add the `allow-same-origin` flag to the header so is there a way I can modify the Doxygen output so that it loads correctly while being served with this CSP sandbox header? It would also be nice not to have to supply custom Javascript, but if that's the only way for now then that is a possibility.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Didi you have a look at the configuration setting `HTML_HEADER` ?

Comment: I'm using Doxygen 1.8.13 (latest on Ubuntu 18.04). I'll checkout that option now!

Comment: The problem will, most likely, be the same with the current doxygen version (1.8.18), though an update doesn't hurt (the 1.8.13 version  is from December, 20, 2016). It is, unfortunately, that that by default no newere versions are available as well.

Comment: I'll try with the latest version to see if it's any different

Comment: Looks like it behaves a little better in the latest version, it loads all the content, but the same error still occurs and the menu ends up being rendered on top of the content. I tried disabling `HTML_DYNAMIC_MENUS` but that didn't seem to solve the menu issue...

Comment: I think best is to look at the possibilities of the configuration setting `HTML_HEADER`, i.e. make and adjusted html header file based on the default doxygen html header file(`doxygen.exe -w html headerFile footerFile styleSheetFile`,). Note this file is version dependent / can change when the doxygen version changes.